# Cloudinary with Angular

Tags: angular, image-manipulation, cloudinary

I am using Cloudinary with Angular, but it's not going as planned.
I am using this documentation:

https://cloudinary.com/documentation/angular_image_manipulation

I can get the image to render using:

```
<cl-image class="img-fluid" [public-id]="section.image.publicId">
</cl-image>
```

I thought that it would automatically resize based on the size of the window; which isn't the case. So I have tried to use transformations.
At first I tried this:

```
<cl-image class="img-fluid" [public-id]="section.image.publicId">
    <cl-transformation height="253" width="568" crop="fill">
    </cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

Which does indeed create the transformation. I thought, cool, now I will add multiple transformations hoping that it would select the correct one when at a certain size:

```
<cl-image class="img-fluid" [public-id]="section.image.publicId">
    <cl-transformation height="388" width="810" crop="fill">
    </cl-transformation>
    <cl-transformation height="253" width="568" crop="fill">
    </cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

But when I do that, it only takes the last transformation. If I change to this:

```
<cl-image class="img-fluid" [public-id]="section.image.publicId">
    <cl-transformation height="253" width="568" crop="fill">
    </cl-transformation>
    <cl-transformation height="388" width="810" crop="fill">
    </cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

It does swap the transformations. I believe it's because of this line in the documentation:

> If you include transformations in both the  and  components, the transformations from the  component are added as the last chain in the resulting URL source.

So, my question is, can I get Cloudinary to serve an image based on the screensize of the requesting device automatically? If not, can I specify transformations for different breakpoints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the `responsive` keyword along with `width:auto` and `dpr:auto` as mentioned [here](https://cloudinary.com/documentation/angular_image_manipulation#responsive_image_settings).

Here is a [CodeSandBox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/cloudinary-responsive-vq6g0?file=/src/app/app.component.html)